# not() function does not work

Tags: jquery

I have the following html elements

```
<div id="featured">
...
    <div class="playlist_box" style="display: block; ">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list" fileid="undefined"> element 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list" fileid="undefined"> element 2</a></li> 
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list" fileid="undefined"> element 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply an onclick event handler to featured that will not be triggered when the area marked with .playlist_box. I tried to deselect various elements, non works, some of them are:

```
  jQuery("#featured").not('.playlist').click(function()...
  jQuery("#featured").not('li').click(function()...
```

It seems that *not()* doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery("#featured:not('.playlist')").click(function()`?

Comment: Hey @ZathrusWriter you're right on that one. But I cannot just accept an answer that I can't make it to work...I am aware this might mean less answers, but it's better than accepting something that I am not 100% sure it works.

Comment: @PotneySwitters absolutely agreed... this is where you can delete your question, self-answer it or even start a bounty on it to drag more people to answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) removes elements from the set of matched elements.*
You're only selecting the div with id `#featured` so `.not()` will just return the div again. Furthermore the class is `playlist_box` not `playlist`.

If you insist on `.not()` then you will have to do something like

```
$("#featured").children().not(".playlist_box").click(...);
```

But why not just

```
$("#featured").on("click", "li.list", function(ev) {
    if ($(this).closest("div").hasClass("playlist_box")) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

One handler to rule them all :D

**Edit:** Added check for parent

Comment: Yea but how can I differentiate then on which of two happens? I would like to have the clickable links doing something else. Can I check on which event triggered the handler?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I got you right but check the edited example

Comment: Thanks andreas :) The first one would work if playlist_box was direct descendant of #featured?(It's quite weird because most of the above make sense but don't work!!)

Comment: Yes, in the first example `.playlist_box` has to be a direct child of `#featured`. If it can be anywhere "below" `#featured` you could change `.children().not(".playlist_box")` to `.find("div").not(".playlist_box")`

Comment: I know I might be breaking your nervers here :D but could check out this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/48eYM/22/). I applied the things discussed before but it gives the opposite results!Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use something like this?

```
$("#featured:not('.playlist')").click(function() {
    //function
});
```

[Here is how to use it.](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it works just fine, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48eYM/1/)

Also, note that you are trying to apply `playlist` which does not exist. You should be looking for `playlist_box` . However, if you do so, it will not work with `.not()` since you are applying `.not()` to the `#featured` which does not have that class, so it will fail, you need to use the filter `:not()`  Or otherwise use `jQuery("a").not('.list').click(function(){`

You may also try doing it like this

`jQuery("#featured:not('.playlist')")`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48eYM/)